# How can I validate a DateTime field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rails-admin

I had two fields `available_to` and `available_from` in a model called `Hotel`. When creating a new `hotel`, we got to specify the date and time! I want to validate these two fields, in such a way that, if one selects `available_to` as *23/2/2015* , the `available_from` should not be *23/2/2014*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way is creating a [custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) within model itself.

Try updating `Hotel` as follows:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_available_to if Proc.new { |h| h.available_from && h.available_to }

  def validate_available_to
    return if available_to > available_from
    errors.add(:available_to, "Date should be at least #{available_from.next.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}")
  end
end
```

**How to use**

```
h = Hotel.new
h.available_from = Date.parse("22/2/2014")
h.available_to = Date.parse("22/2/2014")

h.valid?
# => false

h.errors[:available_to]
# => ["Date should be at least 23/02/2014"]
```

However, when you're extending you validation rules, and code gets complicated, you should consider *moving away* validation from `Model` to separate Validation classes.

Check [`validates_with`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with), with [`ActiveModel::Validator`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) for more.

Hope that helps!